# Detecting Shake Gesture SpriteKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to detect a shake gesture in an `SKScene`.This the code I'm using:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class Menu: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {      

     self.becomeFirstResponder()

     //Game Code

}

  override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

 override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.motionShake {
            //Run Code
        }
    }

    override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
        resignFirstResponder()
    }


}
```

But the `motionEnded` code is not running, it's as if it doesn't detect the shake gesture. This is in an `SKScene` so I'm not sure if the code differs slightly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you can't detect shake events from a `SKScene` subclass, such as `GameScene`. However, you can detect them from a view controller, such as `GameViewController`. When a shake event is triggered, you can call a shake handler in `GameScene` from the view controller.

In your `GameViewController`, add this to detect shake events

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        if let skView = view as? SKView, let scene = skView.scene as? GameScene {
            scene.shake()
        }
    }
}
```

and add this to `GameScene`

```
func shake() {
    print("Shake")
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to detect shake events from multiple `SKScene` subclasses, you can define the following extensions:

```
extension SKScene {
    func shake() {
    }
}

extension SKView {
    open override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let scene = self.scene {
            scene.shake()
        }
    }
}
```

and add the following to the appropriate `SKScene` subclasses

```
override func shake() {
    print("Shake")
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the shake action is different from each SKScene and I have multiple. I need to be able to detect what scene I'm in when it shakes before using the if let skView line, otherwise I think I'll get a crash